# Laravel Validation custom message does not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I create a custom validation in `AppServiceProvider`:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('greaterEqual', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $min_field = $parameters[0];
            $data = $validator->getData();
            $min_value = $data[$min_field];
            return $value >= $min_value;
        });

        Validator::replacer('greaterEqual', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {

            return str_replace(':field', $parameters[0], $message);
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I want to pass custom validation message but not worked and after submit form i receive this message: `validation.greater_equal`.

**This is my validation in controller:**

```
$this->validate($request,[
  'quantity' => 'required|min:1|integer|greaterEqual:sale_quantity',
  'sale_quantity' => 'required|min:0|integer',
],[
  'quantity.greaterEqual' => 'The :attribute number is invalid'
]);
```

What is my mistake?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having a simple mistake. :-)

1- I added the `sale_quantity` translation in:

```
/resources
    /lang
        /en
            validation.php
```

2- I edited code as following:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('greater_equal', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $min_field = $parameters[0];
            $data = $validator->getData();
            $min_value = $data[$min_field];
            return $value >= $min_value;
        });

        Validator::replacer('greater_equal', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {

            return str_replace(':field', trans('validation.attributes.'.$parameters[0]), $message);
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Validation in controller:**

```
$this->validate($request,[
  'quantity' => 'required|min:1|integer|greaterqual:sale_quantity',
  'sale_quantity' => 'required|min:0|integer',
],[
  'quantity.greater_equal' => 'The :attribute number is invalid. The value of :attribute must be greater than :field'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `resolver`...

```
 use API\Extensions\Core\CustomLaravelValidator;

    class CustomValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

        public function boot()
        {
            $this->app['validator']
                 ->resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
            {
                return new CustomLaravelValidator(
                    $translator, 
                    $data, 
                    $rules, 
                    $messages
                );
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Adam, I solved the problem. Thank you for answer.

Comment: What was the solution?